# Problem writing the sequence \@ in inline <code>...</code>-blocks

Tags: bug, markdown, code, syntax-highlighting

When typing answers in an edit-box of the TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange website, which is based on markdown, then from time to time I introduce control-sequence-tokens/sequences of inline-code not via nesting between backticks as in `` `\macro` `` but via nesting between HTML-tags `<code>` and `</code>` as in `<code>\macro</code>`. Usually this yields `\macro`, i.e., the leading backslash `\` of the phrase `\macro` is present.

But when I do this with control-sequence-tokens whose name's first character is `@`, then the preceding backslash doesn't show up:

`<code>\@currenvir</code>`  yields:  `@currenvir`.

(The phrase `\@currenvir` is between HTML-tags `<code>` and `</code>` and as far as I know neither the backslash nor @ is a special/reserved character in HTML.)

Questions:

Why does the preceding backslash not show up in the output at the TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange website if in my markdown/HTML-input it is trailed by `@`?

Am I overlooking some subtle rule regarding syntax of markdown-input or HTML-input or HTML-inside-markdown-input?
If not: Is this a bug?

---

In case things render differently on different browsers here is a screenshot of what I get when viewing with Chromium under Debian Linux:

[image]

Comment: FYI: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/237989

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The answer in that link says that with `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` you need to encode html-entities yourself, but it doesn't specify which characters (besides characters that are special/reserved in HTML) need to be encoded/escaped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The markdown backtick syntax does not only the formatting like the HTML `<code>` block, but it also escapes special characters, so a `\` or a `<` or `>` have no special meaning.  Inside a `<code>` block this escaping does not happen, so a backslash introduces an escape sequence.  To have a backslash you need an escaped backslash, thus: `<code>\\@currenvir</code>`, which renders as `\@currenvir`.  You can see the same thing with other non-alphanumeric characters like `"!@#$%&*()_+=-'?/<>` (in the source of this answer, all of those are preceded by a backslash).

That's also what you have to use when you want to type `</code>` outside of a backtick pair (or a markdown code block): `<code>\</code\></code>` renders as `</code>`, but without the backslashes it would render as  (an empty HTML `<code>` block, plus a stray `</code>`).

Comment: I am a bit confused now: Looking things up in HTML-reference I didn't find backslash to be a special character in HTML. But it is a special character in markdown. Does this mean with HTML inside markdown besides special html-characters you also need to escape special markdown-characters?

Comment: @UlrichDiez I believe so, yes.  `<` and `>` are special for HTML, so you have to escape them (usually with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, but here `\<` and `\>` also work), but since the edit box for stackexchange is officially markdown, rather than HTML, it makes sense that the backslash is only special for markdown and needs escaping.